# regex and urllib.request to __scrape__ links from HTML

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, urllib

I am trying to parse an HTML to extract all values in this regex construction :
*href="http//.+?"*

This is the code:

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
links = re.findall('href="(http://.*?)"',html)
for link in links:
    print(link)
```

But I am getting an error saying :
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlopen(url)` returns a bytes object. So your `html` variable contains bytes as well. You can decode it using something like this:

```
htmlobject = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = htmlobject.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Then you can use `html` which is now a string, in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your `html` is a byte string, use `str(html)`:

```
re.findall(r'href="(http://.*?)"',str(html))
```

Or, use a byte pattern:

```
re.findall(rb'href="(http://.*?)"',html)
```

Comment: @TaufiqueRahman Happy to hear that, please kindly click the grey tick mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like all links on a page, you don't even have to use regex. Because you can just use bs4 to get what you need :-)

```
import requests
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://dr.dk/').text, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
[print(i['href']) for i in links]
```

Hope it was helpful. Good luck with the project ;-)

Comment: Thank you @mama . I will work on it later. I have just begun learning regex in python to parse and all. bs4 will be next chapter.